# Incorrect syntax near '=' in Exec statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

when I execute this:

```
declare @INP_ITBL_NM_SQL char (64)
Exec('
    select '+@INP_ITBL_NM_SQL+' = 
            concat(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.db_schema_name)),LTRIM(RTRIM(b.Name)))
            from '+@db_and_schema+' as a, '+@split_itbl+' as b
            where b.ID = 2 and a.libname = (select c.Name from 
            '+@split_itbl+' as c where c.ID = 1)
')
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '='.

The variables inside the select statement are temporary tables which (need to) change their name every run.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Create the string as a variable and then execute that.

Comment: Instead of exec, use "print" and see which exact line creates the error.

Comment: See this stack overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417688/dynamic-sql-wont-execute and follow the approved solution. It builds the query string into a variable and then executes it

Comment: You really should use a proper join here. You have a cross join that you effectively turning into an inner join with two other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to set the value of a local variable to a value from within dynamic SQL.  So when you print out that SQL text it looks something like:

```
SELECT = concat…
```

You should do this using output parameters with sp_executesql.  Something like the following:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ParamDef nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @INP_ITBL_NM_SQL varchar(100) = ''

SET @ParamDef = N'@INP_ITBL_NM_SQL_OUTPUT varchar(100) OUTPUT';

SET @SQL = N'select @INP_ITBL_NM_SQL_OUTPUT = concat(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.db_schema_name)),LTRIM(RTRIM(b.Name)))
            from '+ @db_and_schema+ ' as a, ' + @split_itbl +' as b
            where b.ID = 2 and a.libname = (select c.Name from 
            '+ @split_itbl +' as c where c.ID = 1)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDef, @INP_ITBL_NM_SQL_OUTPUT=@INP_ITBL_NM_SQL OUTPUT;

SELECT @INP_ITBL_NM_SQL
```